# Check Via API If Field History Tracking Is Enabled?

Tags: api, history-tracking

I want to check with API call if field history tracking is enabled for standard/custom object. Is it possible? If so how?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to check if the history tracking is on or off for an object (and don't need to check which fields), you can rely on the naming pattern of the SObject used to track the history. For custom objects the `__c` is replaced by `__history`, so querying and checking for an error is one approach:

```
public static Boolean hasHistoryTracking(String name) {
     try {
         Database.query('select Id from ' + name + '__history limit 1');
         return true;
     } catch (QueryException e) {
         return false;
     }
}
```

and AFAIK for standard objects just the suffix `History` is added.

I assume (but haven't checked) that the keys returned by [Schema.getGlobalDescribe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) would include the history object names too.

The [Metadata API](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf) has an [enableHistory on CustomObject](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls#L9027) that:

> Indicates whether the object is enabled for history tracking (true) or
>   not (false). Also available for standard objects in API version 29.0
>   and later.

and a [trackHistory flag on CustomField](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls#L10563) that:

> Indicates whether history tracking is enabled for the field (true) or
>   not (false). Also available for standard object fields (picklist and
>   lookup fields only) in API version 30.0 and later. To set trackHistory
>   to true, the enableHistory field on the associated standard or custom
>   object must also be true.

The links I've provided are into the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). This Apex code can be called directly from your Apex code using just a few lines of code. Note that it does involve a web service call from your org back into your org though.